# Fastest way to copy one dimension of 2D vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D vector which im using for complex numbers.
Just for example:

```
vector<vector<double>> Complex;
vector<double> ComplexNumber;
ComplexNumber.push_back(5);  // real part
ComplexNumber.push_back(-4); // imag part
Complex.push_back(ComplexNumber); // Complex[i][0] - real part, [i][1] - imag
```

In depth of my code i need to pull out some part of my Complex vector in to other.
Like, copy from index 10 to 18 real part in some variable (1D vector) and copy from index 10 to 18 imag part in some other variable (1D vector).
Currently im doing this with for cycle:

```
for (int j=0; j<=Samples; j++)
{
  refRealSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j][0] ;
  refImagSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j][1] ;
}
```

This code is the bottleneck of the entire program as profiler shows. Is there any way to improve it?

**Small update:** "Sample" variable is an `int` from 8 to 20, usually 8. Variable `i` comes from an outer for loop.

**Big update:** So, i put out 2D vector and rewrite everything with `complex` class. Also i rewrite my mul operation in "for" cycle. I do not know why, but copying from `complex.imag`  takes more time (more by 2) then from `complex.real` part. After all of this perfomance of code increased from ~5 ms for one sample to ~1.8 ms for one sample. (2.5 ms after i rewrite mul operation and also rewrite entire cycle, this was a very helpfull advice, thanks a lot)

Comment: Why are you using vectors of vectors for representing complex numbers? It probably cannot get less efficient than this.

Comment: I doubt there is much you can do with out changing data layout/types. Make sure you compile with optimizations. You should check if the SIMD kicks in. Then you could go for OpenMP if you have many cores, and given that `Samples` is big. You should really check how many IPC you get, and figure out if its not optimal code, or cache misses, or something else.

Comment: @jasal I honestly don't think so. What makes you think accessing `ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j][0]` is slower than `ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j].real`? Creation of elements will be, but accessing not really IMO.

Comment: @KasiyA it probably comes from another outer loop.

Comment: @luk32 vector has more overhead in terms of memory allocation compared to a simple struct

Comment: @jasal I asked about access, not allocation. You do not allocate any memory when going for `vector::opearator[]`. It doesn't even perform bounduary checks. I can bet is the same as using `struct` in the assembly (as long as the index is fixed, and it is here).

Comment: @luk32: `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` is more cache friendly than `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Comment: Use `std::complex<double>` instead of an `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Look at the reference for it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Comment: @Jarod42 1st one with a valid point, but that is why I suggested checking cache misses. I don't think there is much overhead, but I dunno. People jumped on the `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` bandwagon way too early. Creation is probably much slower vs `std::complex` but accessing is not-so-obvious.

Comment: Oh. Did not expect so many answers, thanks for the help. I totally forgot about "complex" class :(. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Usually if a section is slowing your program down, there are two approaches: (1) make that section faster, or (2) find a way to do that section less often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Samples` is big, you could save some multiplications regarding `i`. So change this:

```
for (int j=0; j<=Samples; j++)
{
  refRealSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j][0] ;
  refImagSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[(i*SignalSampleIndex)+j][1] ;
}
```

to this:

```
int index;
for(i = ..) {                    // assuming your code has a for loop for i
  index = i*SignalSampleIndex;
  for (int j=0; j<=Samples; ++j) // change the ++ as pre-fix
  {
    refRealSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[index+j][0] ;
    refImagSignal[j] = ReferenseComplexSignalsSampled[index+j][1] ;
  }
}
```

That way you do 1 multiplication, instead of `2 * Samples`, as luk32 noticed.

Another approach, as discussed in the comments, you could use a class for representing your complex number. `STL` provides a class for that: [`std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/) .

Then you would have a `vector` with type of `std::complex` and that would keep your data more robust, which might improve `locality`, which `caching` shall take advantage of.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <complex>      // std::complex, std::real
#include <vector>   // std::vector

int main ()
{
  std::vector<std::complex<double> >complex;

  // if you know the amount of your numbers,
  // use a reserve(). Assuming you will insert
  // 100000 numbers, the code would be
  complex.reserve(100000);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
      complex[i] = {0.1, 0.2};

  std::cout << "Real part of 1st element: " << std::real(complex[0]) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]

The multiplications issue is possible to be performed by the compiler, by using an optimization flag. Make sure that you profile your code, when it's compiled with an optimization flag.

**Tip**:

Usually if a section is slowing your program down, there are two approaches: (1) make that section faster, or (2) find a way to do that section less often.

(credits to Psyduck, aka Mooling duck)

In your case, you can tried what I suggested above to make your code faster, but if you would think again your logic and avoid/decrease the times that you copy, then would be rewarded with a boost in the performance.

Comment: You think compiler doesn't do it? My bet is that -O1 is sufficient for this.

Comment: With an optimization flag I think the compiler will do it, but in my answer I do one mul. instead of the two of the OP. It can not harm changing the code as suggested, only improve it.

Comment: It's not an improvement IMO (debatable). However, talking about performance with no optimizations makes no sense in case of c++. Even standard library is slow with `-O0`. You are also wrong about the improvement, you are doing 1 mul instead of 2*`Samples` ;).

Comment: Yes, benchmarking without optimization flag is a bad idea. I will edit my question. And yes you are right about the mul. saving! :) @luk32

Comment: Thanks for poiting to "complex" class! But still, as it looks like it does not solve my problem with copying real and imag part to 1D vectors. I'm still confused is there any other ways of copying them? Or "for" cycle is okay and i really messed up with code somewhere else..

Comment: @Araxnid, in order to copy, you **must** access all the elements, so you can not avoid the `for loop`. You could check if you could create the 1D vectors while you create your `Complex` vector and modify them. But I do not think that this will help much.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `std::vector<double>` for complex numbers is a huge mistake wrt. performance. Why? For several reasons:

- Allocation takes forever. Typical values are somewhere upwards from 200 ns.
- Memory is allocated on the heap. The overhead in terms of space is huge.

  - Typical overhead within the memory allocator: two pointers, i. e. 8 or 16 bytes, depending on your architecture.
  - Overhead of the `std::vector<>` itself: two pointers, another 8 or 16 bytes.
  - Overallocation of the `std::vector<>`: Typical implementations never allocate memory for only two elements. I would estimate this overhead to *at least* six elements (eight elements minimal allocation). That would cause an overhead of 48 bytes.

  So, you end up using somewhat like 80 bytes to store something that would fit into 16.

  This matters, because it means your caches / memory bus have to do five times the work!
- Memory is allocated on the heap. That means your complex numbers are likely scattered. This is another blow to cache efficiency.

If you want to be fast, use either arrays with two elements (doesn't matter if you use C-style arrays or C++ `std::array<>`) or define your complex type as a plain old data `struct`. All three options have the same memory layout, and thus should be equivalent in performance. But I would prefer the `struct` approach since it allows you to overload the operators which is nice for mathematical types like complex numbers, vectors, quaternions, and such.